# How to modify the properties file import by Maven

Tags: java, maven

I add a dependency in Maven, And there is properties file in that dependency ,
I need to modify the file,
How?
[image]

Comment: Artifacts that support configuration usually have a mechanism for overriding their defaults. You should essentially never modify an artifact's internal resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and you shouldn't, modify an artifact's content.

You can, however, override the file by making a copy, modifying it, and saving it with the same name under `src/main/resources`.

Note that whether the runtime sees your edited file or the original one depends heavily on your packaging and on your actual runtime.

Comment: Well, you *can*, because it ends up being local. You *shouldn't*, as you state, and should rely on whatever mechanism the artifact provides for local configuration.

Comment: @DaveNewton "You can", just by virtue of the fact that you can edit the file? Well, technically, yes; although that wouldn't be the same artifact anymore (again, technically...). Unless you're repackaging or doing something you know very well, editing an external stable artifact can have costly consequences...

Comment: AFAICT we don't disagree.

Comment: Thank you all， I want to copy the file , but heard that like a gamble, so I write my own code to replace the dependency .

Comment: @user2802211 that may be your solution, but the best option is to get the library's documentation and read on how to supply non default settings.